# Coldfusion 301 redirect loop (www and non-www point to the same file)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, coldfusion, seo, cflocation

I have searched for this everywhere but all I can find is related to .htaccess files. The server my website is hosted on is not using Apache so I can not use an .htaccess file.

I am trying to send people to the www version of my site whenever they type in the non-www domain. So if user types **domain.com** it will send them to **www.domain.com**. The problem is that they both are already pointing to the same coldfusion file.

I have a redirect set up that works but it is a 302 redirect:

```
<cfif cgi.server_name eq "mydomain.com">
    <cfset cgi.server_name="www.mydomain.com"/>
</cfif>
```

If i change the cfset to:

```
<cflocation statuscode="301" url="www.mydomain.com"/>
```

it creates an infinite redirect loop and I get an error page.

I need to use a 301 redirect so that Google will not double index my page and say that I have duplicate content as it sees the www and non-www as two seperate sites even though it points to same file. Also a 301 redirect will transfer link authority from the non-www to the www domain.

Comment: What is your website hosted on? You will be much better using the server rewrite module to do this for you. Also `cgi.server_name` is not an attribute of [cflocation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cflocation) so its not going to work like that.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using. You can do this with a simple config in IIS.

Comment: cgi.server_name was typed in error, I am using url. Changed the post accordingly.

Comment: Website is hosted on IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in CF you would do something combining your 2 I think.

```
<cfif cgi.server_name IS 'mydomain.com'>
     <cflocation statuscode="301" url="www.mydomain.com"/>
</cfif>
```

FYI - your code is in error for cflocaiton - cgi.server_name is not an attribute of cflocation.

As stated by others you can do this with your web server. Apache or IIS can both handle this task very easily. In IIS you set up a site with mydomain.com as your host header and set it up specifically as a redirect site to www.mydomain.com. good luck!

Comment: I figured it was a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it with ColdFusion then try this in the onRequestStart() method of your Application.cfc file...

```
<cfif cgi.server_name eq "example.com">
    <cflocation statuscode="301" url="http://www.example.com" addToken="no">
</cfif>
```

But as others have said, you're better off redirecting at the web server layer.

Comment: If you're going to put it in application.cfc, you should append `#cgi.script_name#?#cgi.query_string#`. You hardly want every incoming example.com page to redirect to the root, I'd think.